# Ckeditor change width

Tags: ckeditor

I want to change the width and height of the Ckeditor but am not able to change it.
Please know that I want to change it when call CKeditor , I dont want to hard code it inside the config.js...

The bottom code is not working, what do you suggest ?

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editorToday',
          {


            toolbar :
                [
                    { name: 'document', items : [ 'Preview' ] },
                    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
                    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
                    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'] },
                            '/',
                    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
                    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
                    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
                    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
                    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }

                ]

            });


CKEDITOR.instances.editor.resize(500, 400);
```

Comment: Try `CKEDITOR.config.width = 200`, as @user3258189 is suggesting below -- that was the *ONLY* thing that worked for me after hours of Googling.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editorToday',
      {


        toolbar :
            [
                { name: 'document', items : [ 'Preview' ] },
                { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
                { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
                { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak'] },
                        '/',
                { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
                { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
                { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
                { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
                { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] }

            ],
        width: "400px",
        height: "500px"

        });
```

Comment: Just to add, the code most likely failed because CKE loading is asynchronous. Meaning when `.resize(...)` was called CKEditor was not loaded yet so it couldn't resize itself.

Answer (score 3):

The following was taken from [How to change or set width of Ckediotr TextBox area using ASP .Net](http://stepcoder.com/Articles/10002/how-to-set-or-change-height-of-ckediotr-textbox-area-using-asp-net).

## Step1

Create a new ASP.NET webite and name it as Demo_application.

## Step 2

Download Ckeditor from here and add Ckeditor to the root Folder of your Application.

## Step 3

Call the Ckeditor Scripts in your .aspx page like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

## Step 4

Add Ckeditor TextBox to your .aspx file with id  txtCkEditor

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCkEditor" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

## Step 5.

Call the Below JavaScript function to change the default width of Ckeditor TextBox area.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {  
      CKEDITOR.replace('<%=txtCkEditor.ClientID %>');
      CKEDITOR.config.width = 200;
    });
</script>
```

## Step 6

Test Your Application.

Comment: Answer dependent on links are discouraged, can you sumerize the answer and leave the link as a reference?

Comment: That's too complex compared with the simple answer provided over two years ago.

Comment: Actually, after trying many things `CKEDITOR.config.width = 200` was the only thing that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest bracket notation as well as using the ID of the instance:

Try using

CKEDITOR.instances['editorToday'].resize(500, 400);

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work
if i open firebug to check the error, the page stays in the 'loading' state...

Comment: Something in your page hasn't loaded which might be preventing the js from executing properly.

I tried your code but instead used this and it works fine:

CKEDITOR.instances.editorToday.resize(500, 400);

Answer (score 1):

**Simply use this :**

```
CKEDITOR.replace('descCKEditor',{ width: "800px",height: "500px"});
```